# What is the term write time referring to?

Tags: metadata

Date time taken, and date time digitized are the same.  Write time is one hour prior.

What does that mean?

Photo was analyzed on opanda.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Too many unknowns here! What camera? What circumstances? What is "opanda?"

Comment: I would assume Opanda means [this program](https://www.opanda.com/).

Comment: In addition to the comments above, what problem are you trying to solve here?

Comment: Is it possible your camera has been set to take into account Daylight Savings Time and your computer has not? Or vice-versa?

Answer (score 4):

The first two are likely photo metadata (EXIF tags: `DateTimeOriginal` and `DateTimeDigitized` that are normally identical in pictures from cameras), while the third would just be the file time stamp (as you could see it in your file explorer). Difference could be ascribed to DST not being taken in account somewhere.